# Google Chrome crashes when using Remote Desktop Protocol

Tags: google-chrome, remote-access

When I connect to my computer using RDP and visit certain websites (for example mapy.cz), Google Chrome immediately crashes the tab. This does not occur when browsing locally. Any idea what could be the cause and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I've seen something similar and suspected that chrome was using cached data. When I cleared Chrome's cache, the problem was not observed.

Comment: One difference between RDP and using the system locally is the graphics driver used. Maybe Chrome is trying to use hardware acceleration and it's not available when it thinks it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Same topic https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=165636 (Issue 165636:    Multiple users / remote desktop crashes Chrome on Windows 7 / 2008 R2 )