# Chrome Crashes on Remote Desktop

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

Sometimes (not all the time though) when I log into my computer through remote desktop, Chrome dies. Any subsequent time I open Chrome (whether still through the remote connection or even if I log on locally) it opens for a about 5-10 seconds then dies again. A restart fixes this issue until the next time I rdp.

Note, this is not the same as:

- [Google Chrome crashes when using Remote Desktop Protocol](https://superuser.com/questions/408058/google-chrome-crashes-when-using-remote-desktop-protocol) - This is only when visiting certain sites, mine crashes on all sites. Also, once the issue pops up, Chrome crashes even locally.
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=165636 - This is when multiple users connect, which I don't have. Still, I tried unchecking "Enable desktop composition" and it still crashes.

Thanks,
 -Vinay

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/601677/chrome-not-working-on-a-remote-desktop-connection?rq=1 also doesn't solve it (tried running Chrome with the no gpu flag set, still died).

Comment: Also, I've used the RDP client on Windows 10, Windows 7, and Android. All of these cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this! I actually found the solution when Outlook crashed. Outlook's crash allowed me to attach a debugger to see what the issue was (Chrome just disappears, really not helpful). It showed me an access violation in vorbis.acm, which a quick Google search shows is an issue with Remote Desktop and 64-bit machines (not sure what the issue really is, I didn't look to hard). I renamed my vorbis.acm to vorbis.acm.bak, and Chrome stays open (as a bonus, Outlook stops crashing too).

Comment: Vorbis is audio related. Can you please post the stack in a gist ( https://gist.github.com/ ) or on Pastebin? Also, what OS is the client and the server? Thanks!